# getting unique records on the basis of specific associated column - rails active record associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, unique

I have three models. `User`, `Question` and `Attempt`.

Each `User has_many :attempts`,

similarly, `Question has_many :attempts`

and `Attempt belongs_to User` and `Question`

**Required:**

What I want is a method to return a user's last attempt for every question that user has an associated attempt.

I mean if a user has attempted q1, q2 and has 3 attempts for each question, then my method should return last attempt of q1 and last attempt of q2.

**Right now:**
 I have created a method in `User` model.

```
  def last_attempts
    return self.attempts.joins(:question).order("questions.id ASC ,attempts.updated_at DESC").select("DISTINCT ON (question_id) *")
  end
```

**Error:**
This method returns duplicate attempts. (all attempts for every question of that user). all 3 attempts of q1 and all three attempts of q2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an unnecessary join in your query.

You should be able to do the following:

```rb
def questions_last_attempts
  attempts
    .select("DISTINCT ON (question_id) *")
    .order(:question_id, created_at: :desc)
end
```

Which should generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (question_id) * FROM "attempts" WHERE "attempts"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY "attempts"."question_id" ASC, "attempts"."created_at" DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a relationship between `User` and `Question` through `Attempt`.
Then map the `user.questions` ids to select each time the first ordered attempt:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attempts
  has_many :questions, through: :attempts

  def last_attempts
    questions.order(:id).distinct.map do |question|
      attempts.where(question_id: question.id).order(updated_at: :desc).first
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer is also CORRECT. Thanks :)